# Upload a folder of files to google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google `Colab` has not direct access to the local folders. To run the local scripts needs uploading the files to `Colab`. I have a collection of folders and files to upload. I was wondering if there is an efficient way to do so without disturbing the file organization, something like `!git clone...` ?

Comment: I think your best move is to upload it google drive and mount your drive in colab